# Select all elements with height bigger than given

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

How to select items with height bigger then 200px and remember them inside var.

```
var something = $('.myClass').withHeightMoreThan200px();
$('.myClass').each(function(){$(this).height(random(50,500)});
something.hide(); //even if after random change of height some new elements have now height >200px I want it to affect only those remembered before.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var something = $('.myClass').filter(function(){
    return $(this).height() > 200;
});
```